# Sharing industry data with academic class contracts?

Tags: data-mining, dataset

Could someone point me to a standard data sharing agreement? I have an interesting data set that I want to share with my local university for  their Data Mining class. The data set includes time-series and email statistics. All domains and IPs are anonymized before release.

Main points:

1. Use at your own risk
2. Protect my company and client's privacy
3. Cite my company
4. Do not re-share without permission

Am I missing anything important here?